# for loop to change buttons titles in Swift

Tags: for-loop, swift

I'd like to use a for loop to change the title of 5 buttons. I'd like to use i as the variable to replace the number.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 6; ++i) {     

let buttonName = button0 + i                  
buttonName.setTitle("Sydvestpynten", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

}
```

My buttons are called button01, button02, etc.

The above code doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think you can construct variable names as such during runtime. Please check my answer for a solution

Comment: While Rajeev's answer is correct for what you asked, I suspect you might be better off using an `IBOutletCollection` which allows you to put an array of buttons into one outlet, see here for more info http://mikezornek.com/2013/11/27/iboutletcollection/

Comment: Thanks for that sbarrow. Been meaning to check it out myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let buttons = [button01, button02, button03...]
for button in buttons {
    button.setTitle("Sydvestpynten", forState: .Normal)
}
```

It would probably be a good idea to make the array a property.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot create variable names on the fly like you're trying to do. Things like that only work in a few (scripting) languages and even then are considered to be a bad practice.

But there's an easy workaround: use an array. Either store your buttons in an array instead of creating a lot of variables or construct your array on the fly:

```
for button in [button01, button02, button03, button04, button05, button05] {
    button.setTitle("Sydvestpynten", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

If you're using Interface Builder, remember that you can also use IBOutletCollections with Swift. The syntax is a bit different, though:

```
@IBOutlet var buttons: Array<UIButton>
```

In Interface Builder, you can then assign several buttons to the same outlet (`buttons`).

Answer (score 0):

Try storing your buttons in an array and then looping through the array and setting the titles instead.

```
var arrayOfButtons:[UIButton] = []

//add buttons here using arrayOfButtons.append(myButton)

for button in arrayOfButtons
{
    button.setTitle("title", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```